# regex matching content that's between angle brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I convert all multiple white space inside any given HTML element to a single space using regex and preg_replace in php?

Eg: `<div  class="myClass"    jsaction="UjQMac:.CLIENT"   data-id="3739" >Edit</div>`

Cleaned: `<div class="myClass" jsaction="UjQMac" data-id="3739">Edit</div>` All multiple spaces removed and only single spaces retained. Also, the  `>` is replaced with a `>`

I've been trying unsuccessfully with this regex `\<(\s+)\>`. Can you help?

**Edit:**
The regex `(?:(\s{2,})|(\s>))` from the answer below works fine, but does not match only between `<` & `>`

Comment: should not be done using regex. Use HTML DOM parser

Comment: @anubhava althought I agree with you, when people try to parse HTML with RegEx, I think this case is safe for RegEx usage. Or perhaps there's something I'm missing

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Cid consider this html `<div title="3 > 2"  class="myClass"  jsaction="UjQMac"  data-id="3739">Edit</div>` and how that might complicate  a regex solution.

Comment: Good point @WesleySmith I didn't realized OP wanted to match the tag

Answer (score 0):

This will do it: `(?:(\s{2,})|(\s>))`

It matches any whitespace character that appears 2x or more often and also `>` with a leading  .

See: https://regex101.com/r/NN9YUU/2/

Comment: I'm trying to get it to match only what's in between `<` & `>`. This'll match an entire string. It works great though. If you see the regex i'm using in my question `\<(\s+)\>`. I did try putting your solution into my regex, but it won't work.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/NN9YUU/4/

Comment: Can you help with the `<` & `>` part?

Comment: @Norman not really, any regex approach to this is doomed to failure. RegEx is not suited for this type of application. Any one you use, we'll be able to make it fail.

Comment: I won't be working with data that'll submitted by the public. This is only to cleanup a huge garbled output from some blog backup.

Comment: This issue isnt specific to data submitted by the public. Please read the post I linked to in my comment on the question

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/NN9YUU/5/